# What is the difference between follow and +1

Tags: google-plus

i have page in google plus. in my page followers are 170. i add google badge in my website. in that google badge box showing +300 and +1 button.
my google page not showing that `+1` button, what is the different between both follow and +1.
how can i show +1 button on my google page.

any one can give me best answer.

Thank You.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something - just **NOT** programming...

Comment: His last question could be if he's programming his own website.

Comment: @marc_s i don't know how to add +1 button code on my page.that is my problem.

Answer (score 3):

[The Follow Button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/follow/) applies to your Google+ account (or Page). For example, adding a user to your Circles.
[The +1 Button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/) is about a particular piece of [content that grabbed your attention](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1047397?hl=en). For example, +1ing an article.